# Процесс отмены платежа в google play на сервере

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Есть сервер игры, клиент отправляет токен туда после покупки, дальше проверка платежа и выдача внутриигрового контента. Но вот столкнулся с проблемой, если клиент отменит платеж, то сервер не получает никакого уведомления. Есть способы где нибудь привязать url куда обратится гугл в случае отмены? Или ставить задачу через 2 часа перепроверять покупку, но тогда может быть так что игрок уже потратил то что ему выдали? Кто как решает такую поблему?